# Is this called JavaScript Component?

Tags: javascript

In a video on Yotube, this piece of JavaScript code is called as "Component". While I was searching about JavaScript component, most of results on Google is about React Components.

```
const mover = {
  move(){
    console.log("Moved!")
  }
}
```

What is this called in JavaScript?

Comment: you are declaring an object `mover` with a single method `move()` that prints to the console Moved!

Answer (score 0):

`mover` is an object as you can see printed in this snippet.

```js
const mover = {
  move(){
    console.log("Moved!")
  }
}

console.log(typeof(mover))
```

In javascript objects can be represented in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) which is a standard text-based format for representing structured data based on JavaScript object syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It is a javascript object, in this case it has a function called "move", some tests:

```js
const mover = {
  move(){
    console.log("Moved!")
  }
}

console.log(typeof mover)
console.log(mover)
console.log(typeof mover.move)
console.log(mover.move)
mover.move()
```